# Fetch all fields and values in a form view odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to fetch all fields and its values which are in a form view into a dictionary.
Example, in `customer form view`, need to get all values into a dictionary in a button function.
I tried with `fields_get()`, `fields_view_get` and `name_get`. But no luck.
Is there any predefined function or any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the solution.`self.read()` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.env.cr.execute("""select * from res_partner where id=%s""",(self.id,))
line_list = [i for i in self.env.cr.dictfetchall()]
for i in line_list:
    print i['fieldname']
```

or use orm methods

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this :**

```
for rec in your_list_of_dictionary:
    print rec #this rec variable contains dictionary
```